# PHP odbc_fetch_row VERY SLOW

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

In summary, when using odbc_fetch_row() with SQL Server 2012 in PHP it takes 17 seconds to loop through 525 results.

Environment:

- Mac OS X 10.9
- Apache (that ships with os x)
- PHP 5.5.8 from http://php-osx.liip.ch/
- ODBC Driver: Actual SQL Server
- SQL Server 2012

odbc.ini file contents:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
theDb           = Actual SQL Server

[theDb]
Driver         = /Library/ODBC/Actual SQL Server.bundle/Contents/MacOS/atsqlsrv.so
Description    = Production SQL Server
Server         = [some address]
Database       = [some db]
ServerName     = theDb
host           = [some address]
```

PHP Test Page:

```
<?php

$userID="[user]";
$password="[password]";
$driverSourceString="theDb";

$dbc = odbc_connect($driverSourceString, $userID, $password);

$time_start=0;

function startTimer(){
    global $time_start;
    $time_start = microtime(true);
}

function printTimer(){
    global $time_start;
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    echo sprintf('%f', $time);
    echo " Seconds";
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>SQL TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

    <pre>

    Connection:
    <?php
        startTimer();
        $dbc = odbc_connect($driverSourceString, $userID, $password);
        printTimer();
    ?>


    Query:
    <?php
        startTimer();
        $query = "SELECT m.firstName + ' ' + m.lastName AS username FROM models m ORDER BY lastName ASC";
        $result = odbc_exec($dbc, $query);
        printTimer();
    ?>


    Fetchrow:
    <?php
        startTimer();
        while(odbc_fetch_row($result))
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        printTimer();
    ?>

    </pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Connection:
0.000129 Seconds

Query:
0.061282 Seconds

Fetchrow:
15.795249 Seconds (WHY SO LONG??)
```

Comment: Did you check if it's ALL rows being equaly slow or just certain rows? e.g. put your printTimer() inside the fetch loop and see what the per-row fetch times are.

Comment: We did do that and found it's all rows. Oddly, when we run this on a Windows Server it works fine.

Answer (score 14):

I also hade some serious performance issues with fetching results from a MSSQL database with php odbc. 
For me, the solution was to specify cursor type in the connection:

```
$con = odbc_connect([dsn], [user], [pwd], SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC)
```